# Dell studio 1555 motherboard failure, won't boot up. What could have gone wrong?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure, gpu

Suddenly my Dell Studio 1555 laptop would not boot up and I suspect some sort of motherboard failure. When I press the power button it lights up, however nothing shows up on the screen, neither does the CPU fan start spinning. There is no beeping (even if I take out the two RAM modules from the motherboard). I have performed multiple tests and checks with all peripherals disconnected from the motherboard (optical drive, HDD, etc.) and here are some of things I've tried or found out:

- Cleaning fan & heatsink - did not help
- Multiple static discharges - did not help.
- Swapping the memory modules and their slots one at a time - did not
  help.
- Taking out the CMOS battery - did not help.
- Applying new thermal pads and thermal paste - did not help.

The issue is not with the display since the display test passes successfully (i.e. holding D while pressing the power button)
The battery is fully loaded and the charger works well.
If the optical drive is connected to the motherboard, I could hear that it makes some noise when I press the power button.
I have also noticed that the heatsink heats up quite a lot if I leave the motherboard powered up for about a minute, although the thermal pads and the thermal paste are new. With the heatsink removed, the processor and the GPU chip heat up to the level where you cant touch them in about 15-20 seconds.

Given that I am 99% sure that the issue is with the motherboard, is there any way in which I can at least understand which mobo component has failed? Any last resorts and checks before trying to bake it to reflow any loose connections?

Comment: Does it matter which part on the motherboard failed?  It could be as simple as a capacitor or a resistor to a IC.  Finding what part failed without a schematic of the motherboard won't be possible, even with one it would be nearly impossible.

Comment: I guess it does not matter that much since the whole motherboard has to be replaced, however I was curious to find out what has gone wrong. Is there a way in which I can rule out the GPU or CPU from the list of potential reasons?

Comment: You would have to use a different CPU or GPU in order to determine that.

Comment: "With the heatsink removed, the processor and the GPU chip heat up to the level where you cant touch them in about 15-20 seconds. " - Why are you even testing this?  This is normal, your CPU and GPU both need a heatsink in order to function.